# invalid gridOptions property 'serverSideInfiniteScroll'

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

my ag-grid version is 25.3 and it's enterprise version.
But

```
<ag-grid-angular [serverSideInfiniteScroll]="true"></ag-grid-angular>
```

will alert invalid gridOptions property 'serverSideInfiniteScroll'.

After I setup the ag-grid, It seem it ignore this setting. Then I only can fetch one time data. Even I scroll to bottom. it don't call api to fetch data.

Comment: There's too little code in your question to tell. Please edit your question and add more code, especially how you set up the server side row model. Or attach Plunker based [the one from docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/server-side-model-infinite-scroll/#example-infinite-scroll).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 25.3 then you will want to access the documentation for 25.3. You are trying to use a new property that is part of v28.

Here is the link to 25.3 Server Side Docs

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.3.0/javascript-grid/server-side-model/